# jquery to load excel file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what is the the easiest way to open an excel file , check each cell in each row for consistency (e.g column1 must be between the values of 6 and 15 - if not then do not bind that row.
Once all rows are checked for consistency then bind only the rows that match the check.

I want to do this on the client side and must work in chrome

**Update - Based on feedback i am willing to put the file on the server and somehow open it from there if that makes this possible?**

Comment: There won't be an easy way that is entirely client-side. unless you're working with say a CSV file. If you want to open a xls (97-2003?) or the newer xlsx you will need to do a lot of work to get to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/csv2table

Good luck!